# using for loop and asynchronus services in angular js

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, asynchronous

I want to iterate over a loop and call a service (which is asynchronus) for each item -

```
 for(var i=0;i<$scope.objs.length;i++) {
        var obj= $scope.objs[i];            
        api.invoke({
            //parameters
        }).then(function (members) {
            $scope.setInfo(obj.name,members);   
        }, function (fail) {
            console.log("failed");
        });  
    }
```

But,  as it is asynchronus , obj value is getting ovrewritten before I can send it to the method - setInfo(). How can I avoid it?

Comment: it would be be better to avoid calling api in a loop

Comment: i have to cal api for each array object. How can I do it then? (if not loop)

Comment: pass array of input to server.. get array of responses

Comment: You can pass array of objects in $scope.setInfo and let api call each time and you can obviously put a loop inside defination of setInfo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using `angular.forEach` which would have `value` that will be available for that particular function level.

**Code**

```
angular.forEach($scope.objs, function(value, index) {
    api.invoke({
        //parameters
    }).then(function(members) {
        $scope.setInfo(value.name, members);
    }, function(fail) {
        console.log("failed");
    });
})
```

**OR** same thing can be done by creating anonymous function.